# Is there a way to load an Instances object from WEKA without the long loading time?

Tags: java, weka

When I load a .csv file with weka.core.converters.CSVLoader, weka tries to load a bunch of stuff I dont need (like load database drivers- see below).
I just need the Instances object as quickly as possible so I can do some operations with it.

**Is there a way to quickly load the object without all the unnecessary overhead?**

Newer versions of Weka are even slower (with more stuff loaded).

Thanks,
Todd

```
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
```

Comment: This only happens once when you start the GUI and in my case, it starts up in 1-2 seconds (although most of the time is spend wit hthe Java GUI itself, bot with the loading). If you want raw speed, you could write a simple Java app that does exactly what you want with the help of weka.jar as a library that holds al the functionallity you want.

Comment: This happens to me as well even when using Weka via the Command Line. These 1/2 seconds of loading can delay experiments quite badly if you are doing hundreds them.

Comment: I imported weka source files as a project in eclipse with no hassle and linked it to my project. This way, you can call only the functions you need!

Answer (score 1):

Well I think if you care about the performance you should run you experiment from a Java program using *Weka API* not from GUI or Command Line.

But anyways, there are few things you can do to minimize what Weka loads in the initializing:

1- Remove what you do not need from the folder `%USER_DIR%\wekafiles\packages`, because Weka load these files when it starts

2- Within *Weka* source code change the file `weka.experiment.DatabaseUtils.props` and comment the below line which will limit the database drivers that Weka loads.

```
#jdbcDriver=RmiJdbc.RJDriver,jdbc.idbDriver,org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver,com.mckoi.JDBCDriver,org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

In general, you can search for the message that Weka displays on the console during the initialization e.g. `"Loading properties and plugins"` and search for it in Weka source code and see what you can safely disable.